# Get the first and last date of next month in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I get the first and last day of next month to be used in the where clause?

Comment: SELECT DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS 'FIRST DAY OF NEXT MONTH';

SELECT DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'LAST DAY OF NEXT MONTH'

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT

DATE_SUB(
    LAST_DAY(
        DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    ), 
    INTERVAL DAY(
        LAST_DAY(
            DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        )
    )-1 DAY
) AS firstOfNextMonth,

LAST_DAY(
    DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
)AS lastOfNextMonth
```

Comment: For more MySQL time-related functions like this one, see [this blog post](http://sys-exit.blogspot.com/2013/06/mysql-today-tomorrow-yesterday-this.html)

Comment: @OMGPonies, Use `curdate` instead of `now()` because we don't need the timings. Also, for first day, it's more straightforward to [simply minus the number of days of the current month](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28844641/632951). It's also faster because we are doing only a single `date_sub()` call and a single `day()` call.

Answer (score 30):

For the last day of next month, you can use the [`LAST_DAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
+-------------------------------------------------+
| LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 2010-07-31                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Some tested edge cases:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD('2010-01-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
+----------------------------------------------------+
| LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD('2010-01-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 2010-02-28                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD('2010-02-28', INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
+----------------------------------------------------+
| LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD('2010-02-28', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 2010-03-31                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD('2010-08-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
+----------------------------------------------------+
| LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD('2010-08-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 2010-09-30                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is also a tricky use of the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to get the first day of a month. You can use it as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-01') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2010-07-01                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Therefore:

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AS
            FirstDayOfNextMonth,
         LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS
            LastDayOfNextMonth;

+---------------------+--------------------+
| FirstDayOfNextMonth | LastDayOfNextMonth |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2010-07-01          | 2010-07-31         |
+---------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Daneil, DATE_FORMAT returns you a `var_string`, not a date. Use my solution instead.

Answer (score 20):

**First day** of next month is simply last day of this month + 1:

```
select adddate(last_day(curdate()), 1)
```

**Last day** of next month is simply last day of (today + 1 month):

```
select last_day(curdate() + interval 1 month))
```

These are the most straightforward solutions. You'll not be able to find a shorter one.

---

If you need the first day of the **current** month, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28966866/632951

Answer (score 3):

```
# FIRST date of next month
select date_sub(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 month), interval day(curdate())-1 day);

# LAST date of next month
select date_sub(date_add(curdate(), interval 2 month), interval day(curdate()) day);
```

not sure that's the shortest queries, but they do work

Answer (score 2):

As @DanielVassallo explained it, retrieving the last day of next month is easy:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

To retrieve the first day, you could first define a custom `FIRST_DAY` function (unfortunately MySQL does not provide any):

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION FIRST_DAY(day DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(day, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1);
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

And then you could do:

```
SELECT FIRST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

Comment: Can't we simply write (last_day(current_date() + interval 1 month)) ?

Comment: @UncleIroh, Yes we can, that works too. But there's actually an **even shorter** solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28844641/632951

Answer (score 1):

To get first date of next month :-`select LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

To get last date of next month :-`select LAST_DAY(NOW()+  INTERVAL 1 Month)`

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql you have perfect date truncation functions.

For MySQL, I found a discussion [here](http://dba-mysql.blogspot.com/2007/12/first-day-of-month.html) which might give some ideas.

Comment: Good link actually, but you want to include the contents of it within this page. What do you mean by date truncation functions anyway?

Answer (score 0):

```
select Convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(Day, 1, getdate() - Day(getdate()) + 1) -1,105)

select Convert(varchar(10),getdate(),105)

select year(getdate())
```

Comment: I think your answer is for SQL Server ;).

Answer (score 0):

Here is all Possible solutions. Hope this will help ... Just Run this to get All details

```
SELECT 

  DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS GetLastDay, 
  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') AS GetTodaysDate,
  DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS Add7DaysFromTodaysDate,
  DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS Substract7DaysFromTodaysDate,
  DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS Add1MonthFromTodaysDate,
  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS FirstDayCurrentMonth , 
  LAST_DAY(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')) AS lastDayCurrentMonth,
  DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 
            INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))-1 DAY) AS FirstOfNextMont007,
  LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS lastOfpREMonth,
  DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 
            INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))-1 DAY) AS FirstOfNextMonth,
   LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS lastOfNextMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter query:

```
SELECT
ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(NOW()), 1) AS firstOfNextMonth,
LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS lastOfNextMonth
```

Comment: [`curdate` is better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28844641/632951) than `now` in terms of both speed and intention conveyance. Also, `+` is better than `DATE_ADD` in terms of both readability and command length.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY('2020-12-14'),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS 'FIRST DAY OF NEXT MONTH';
        +----------------------------+
        | FIRST DAY OF NEXT MONTH |
        +----------------------------+
        | 2021-01-01                 |
        +----------------------------+
        1 row in set (1.06 sec)
        
SELECT DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS 'LAST DAY OF NEXT MONTH';
        +------------------------+
        | LAST DAY OF NEXT MONTH |
        +------------------------+
        | 2020-09-30             |
        +------------------------+
        1 row in set (0.51 sec)
```