# How to get first day of every corresponding month in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

I want to get first day of every corresponding month of current year. For example, if user selects '2010-06-15', query demands to run from '2010-06-01' instead of '2010-06-15'.

Please help me how to calculate first day from selected date. Currently, I am trying to get desirable using following mysql select query:

```
Select
  DAYOFMONTH(hrm_attendanceregister.Date) >=
  DAYOFMONTH(
    DATE_SUB('2010-07-17', INTERVAL - DAYOFMONTH('2010-07-17') + 1 DAY
  )
FROM
  hrm_attendanceregister;
```

Thanks

Comment: I added a detailed response to this question years ago and a moderator deleted it for whatever reason. This is why I don't answer questions on this website anymore. I'm not going to repost the answer just for it to be deleted again, but you can read a comparison of the various ways to achieve this on [my blog](https://kb.zensoft.hu/mysql-get-the-first-day-of-the-month-for-a-given-date/) where I benchmark all the methods I could find to get the first day of the month for a given day. Let's see how long it takes for this comment to be deleted…

Answer (score 83):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
select CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE);
```

Comment: This is unnecessary overhead. You are converting the date to string then back to date again. My solution is much better.

Comment: This is way better than my answer.

Answer (score 39):

You can use the [LAST_DAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function provided by MySQL to retrieve the last day of any month, that's easy:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY('2010-06-15');
```

Will return:

```
2010-06-30
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not provide any `FIRST_DAY` function to retrieve the first day of a month (not sure why). But given the last day, you can add a day and subtract a month to get the first day. Thus you can define a custom function:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION FIRST_DAY(day DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(day, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1);
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

That way:

```
SELECT FIRST_DAY('2010-06-15');
```

Will return:

```
2010-06-01
```

Comment: Your `FIRST_DAY` solution is semantically indirect because you are adding 1 day to the last day of the previous month instead of simply subtracting the number of days the current date has. Refer to my solution.

Answer (score 34):

There is actually a straightforward solution since the first day of the month is simply `today - (day_of_month_in_today - 1)`:

```
select now() - interval (day(now())-1) day
```

Contrast that with the [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158513/632951) which are extremely roundabout and indirect.

---

Also, since we are not interested in the time component, [`curdate()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) is a better (and faster) function than `now()`. We can also take advantage of  [`subdate()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate)'s 2-arity overload since that is more performant than using `interval`. So a better solution is:

```
select subdate(curdate(), (day(curdate())-1))
```

Comment: good answer, I think this is the most elegant and efficient solution

Comment: -1 for arrogant tone and comments. Have you benchmarked to show that your method is the most efficient? I can't imagine any of the solutions would be noticeably slow on a typical dataset.

Comment: FYI - This solution doesn't work properly if the date stamp has a time component.

Comment: 'Please help me how to calculate first day from selected date'... This doesn't not answer the O.P.s question... this only works for the current month.

Comment: This is the best one (zealotry aside), it does't convert date to string then parse the string.

Answer (score 16):

This is old but this might be helpful for new human web crawlers XD

For the first day of the current month you can use:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Comment: Inefficient. Uses one date subtraction and one date addition when actually only one date subtraction is needed. Refer to my solution.

Comment: You'd think so, but this is about 30% faster when I ran @user3430223 benchmarks

Answer (score 10):

You can use `EXTRACT` to get the date parts you want:

```
EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM DATE('2011-09-28') )
-- 201109
```

This works well for grouping.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to calculate the first day of a month, and the following are the performance in my computer (you may try this on your own computer)

And the winner is `LAST_DAY(@D - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day`

```
set @D=curdate();

select BENCHMARK(100000000, subdate(@D, (day(@D)-1))); -- 33 seconds
SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, @D - INTERVAL (day(@D) - 1) DAY); -- 33 seconds
SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, cast(DATE_FORMAT(@D, '%Y-%m-01') as date)); -- 29 seconds
SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, LAST_DAY(@D - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day); -- 26 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use DATE_FORMAT() function in order to get the first day of any date field.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01') as FIRST_DAY_CURRENT_MONTH 
FROM dual;
```

Change Curdate() with any other Date field like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date,'%Y-%m-01') AS FIRST_DAY_SALES_MONTH 
FROM Company.Sales;
```

Then, using your own question:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  hrm_attendanceregister
WHERE
hrm_attendanceregister.Date) >=
 DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01')
```

You can change CURDATE() with any other given date.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one has proposed something akin to this (I do not know how performant it is):

```
CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURDATE()), MONTH(CURDATE()), '1')
```

Additional date operations could be performed to remove formatting, if necessary

Answer (score 2):

The solutions that use `last_day()` and then add/subtract a month and a day are not interchangeable.

Example:

```
date_sub(date_add(last_day(curdate()), interval 1 day), interval 3 month)
```

always works for any supplied number of months you want to go back

```
date_add(date_sub(last_day(now()), interval 3 month), interval 1 day)
```

will fail in some cases, for instance if your current month has 30 days and the month you're subtracting back to (and then adding a day) has 31.

Answer (score 1):

use [date_format](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_date_format.asp) method and check just month & year

```
select * from table_name where date_format(date_column, "%Y-%m")="2010-06"
```

Comment: [Don't use date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298288/how-to-get-first-day-of-every-corresponding-month-in-mysql/28966866#comment-46185420), it's slow.

Answer (score 1):

Slow (17s):

```
SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, current_date - INTERVAL (day(current_date) - 1) DAY); 
SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, cast(DATE_FORMAT(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') as date));
```

If you don't need a date type this is faster:
Fast (6s):

```
SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01'));
SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, DATE_FORMAT(current_date, '%Y-%m-01'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT LAST_DAY(date) as last_date, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-01') AS fisrt_date FROM table_name
```

> date=your column name

Answer (score 0):

```
date_add(subdate(curdate(), interval day(?) day), interval 1 day)
```

change the ? for the corresponding date

Comment: Inefficient because you use one date addition and one date subtraction when only one date subtraction is needed. Also, [instead of `date_add`, use the 2-arity `AddDate`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28966866/632951) which is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
 date(SUBDATE("Added Time", INTERVAL (day("Added Time") -1) day))
```

** *replace "Added Time" with column name*

**Use Cases:**

1. If you want to reset all date fields except **Month** and **Year**.
2. If you want to retain the **column format** as "date". (not as "text" or "number")

Answer (score 0):

I might be late for this answer but this works for me

SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(datetime_column, '%Y-%m-01') AS first_date,
LAST_DAY(datetime_column) AS last_date
FROM your_table;

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34655588)

Answer (score -1):

```
select big.* from
(select @date := '2010-06-15')var
straight_join 
(select * from your_table where date_column >= concat(year(@date),'-',month(@date),'-01'))big;
```

This will not create a full table scan.