# MySQL round date to the start of the week and month

Tags: mysql, date

For "2012-07-12", how can I get the start of the week, i.e., "2012-07-08", and start of the month, i.e., "2012-07-01"?

Comment: how are you inserting the data? from a stored proc? from a program? are you wanting to insert the data "rounded" or "round" the data when you return it from the DB?

Comment: The data are already there with the full date. For some queries, I want to round the date.

Comment: Duplicate (day of week): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944055/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-mysql

Comment: Duplicate (day of month): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298288/how-to-get-first-day-of-every-corresponding-month-in-mysql

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First day of the month:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-07-12', '%Y-%m-01');
```

output: 2007-07-01

First day of the week:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2007-07-12', INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK('2007-07-12')-1 DAY);
```

output: 2007-07-08

MySQL reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` is definitely a clean and easy way to round. Thanks.

Comment: Noting that this truncates to Sunday as the start of the week, unlike postgres, which truncates to Mondays.

Answer (score 12):

Same answer as [Borophyll's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043792/borophyll), but I have changed the behavior of the first day of the month to return a date, not just a string which avoids date formatting/parsing mentioned in [user151220's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007178/user151220) answer.

First day of the month:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2007-07-12', INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH('2007-07-12') - 1 DAY);
```

output: `2007-07-01`

First day of the week:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2007-07-12', INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK('2007-07-12') - 1 DAY);
```

output: `2007-07-08`

MySQL reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 4):

For those who need Monday as the first day of the week:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2007-07-12', INTERVAL WEEKDAY('2007-07-12') DAY);
```

output: 2007-07-09

This relies on the [WEEKDAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function, which starts with Monday instead of [DAYOFWEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek), which starts with Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

The DATE_FORMAT reply from Borophyll is very good, but gives a string rather than a date.  So can't be compared easily.

If you need to use this as a comparison to a date field, use **str_to_date** to reverse it back to date rather than string.

```
select x from y where date >= str_to_date( DATE_FORMAT(now()-interval 12 month,'Y-%m-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

If you are (say) looking at 12 months sales figures, but you want to always start off from the 1st of a month.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you want to just code it and forget about it, it will use datetime now and always return MTD results-

```
where date_completed between date_sub(date(now()), INTERVAL dayofmonth(now()) -1 day) and now()
```