# MySQL query to return a list of months

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to get a list of months back if a table has this structure:

```
Table
id    | payment  | date
1001    200.00     2013-10-11
1001    100.00     2013-11-02
1002    250.00     2014-01-23
1003    320.00     2014-02-02
1004    300.00     2014-03-04
1004     90.00     2014-03-05
1004     50.00     2014-04-21
1005    400.00     2014-04-21
```

I want to get a list back where the month is **unique** like so:

```
Months
2013-10-01
2013-11-01
2014-01-01
2014-02-01
2014-03-01
2014-04-01
```

Is that doable? Or would I have to have some other kind of query and play with it in PHP?

Comment: If you have a Calendar table (essentially, a table with all dates in it, plus a few related attributes split off) this becomes trivial.  Do you need any _other_ information from this table, or you just want the list of dates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01') as Months from Table GROUP BY Months;
```

This:

- Selects the date in the format you specified (i.e., as first day of month)
- Groups by month so that you get one record returned for each month

Comment: Sorry, this returns some wonky results.

Comment: explain "wonky results"

Answer (score 2):

try this:
`select DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01') as Months from Table group by Months`

based off this question: [MySQL round date to the start of the week and month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461420/mysql-round-date-to-the-start-of-the-week-and-month)

and this doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: you didn't say that in the question ;)

Comment: Sorry, thought the "what I want the list to look like" implied it.

Comment: better to be explicit-- at least 2 of us didn't get it

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

`SELECT date FROM tableName GROUP BY date;`

Answer (score 1):

this will group your dates by month of each date

```
SELECT 
    DATE(date) as your_date 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY MONTH(your_date);
```

to handle multiple years, you can also group by year..

```
GROUP BY MONTH(your_date), YEAR(your_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01') FROM Table
```