# MySQL - Obtain the records made during the current week

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm making a panel where I want to show the number of records made per day, week, month and year.

When a new record is made, the date with the format d/m/Y is saved in the database in a column of the table.

For example to obtain how many records have been made in a day I use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}emails WHERE registration_date = '$today'
```

What I want to achieve is to know how many records I have obtained in the week in which we are knowing that the week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday.

The truth is that I have no great idea to make queries and any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461420/mysql-round-date-to-the-start-of-the-week-and-month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get your goal.

Here is query to get count for one week of some date:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}emails 
WHERE registration_date BETWEEN 
      DATE_ADD($yourDate, INTERVAL - WEEKDAY($yourDate) DAY),
      DATE_ADD($yourDate, INTERVAL (7 - WEEKDAY($yourDate)) DAY)
```

Comment: Based on your idea, I'm getting closer, I think, but it gives me back 0. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}emails WHERE registration_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD('$today', INTERVAL - WEEKDAY('$today') DAY) AND DATE_ADD('$today', INTERVAL (7 - WEEKDAY('$today')) DAY)`

Comment: The question is - what is your `$today` value contain?

Comment: $today is current day in string. `$today = (string)date('d/m/Y')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215354/php-date-format-when-inserting-into-datetime-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare dates against a range, for example, to get dates for the last week:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE (thedate >= DATE_SUB(INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) AND
(thedate < DATE());
```

MySQL has several date functions for that.