# How many times a event fired in mysql

Tags: mysql

I created an event in MYSQL with schedule date. For example the event fire on current month first date.

Am using the below query to select the current month first date

```
select CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') as DATE)
```

My doubt is how many time the event fire on that date.

Comment: you can see by using prefix  `EXPLAIN` on your query  `"EXPLAIN SELECT...."`

Comment: @diEcho My question is how many times the event fired in a day..

Comment: Can you show the whole `CREATE EVENT` statement?

Comment: If your event starts every first day of every month, it will be fired once a month. Why do you want to count - how many times the event fired in a day?

Comment: It fires on every day ,on your given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can analyze your query using [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

```
"EXPLAIN SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') as DATE)";
```

### alternative:

if you want to find first day of current month then you can can create a custom function

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION FIRST_DAY(day DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(day, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1);
END;;
DELIMITER ;
That way:
```

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298288/how-to-get-first-day-of-every-corresponding-month-in-mysql)

and then  call

```
SELECT FIRST_DAY(DATE(NOW()));
```