# How to set up a WHILE loop with IF statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, do-while

I would like to create a stored routine for MySQL that figures out the number of business or working days for a month (Working Days are Monday thru Friday).

It's a syntax error however I don't know what the syntax error is.  All it tells me is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'WHILE(@daycount < @totaldays) DO IF (WEEKDAY(@checkweekday) < 6)
> THEN ' at line 2

My Syntax Error is in the following:

```
WHILE(@daycount < @totaldays) DO
      IF (WEEKDAY(@checkweekday) < 6) THEN
```

My Code:

```
SELECT MONTH(CURDATE()) INTO @curmonth;
SELECT MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) INTO @curmonthname;
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE())) INTO @totaldays;
SELECT FIRST_DAY(CURDATE()) INTO @checkweekday;
SELECT DAY(@checkweekday) INTO @checkday;
SET @daycount = 0;
SET @workdays = 0;

BEGIN
  WHILE(@daycount < @totaldays) DO
      IF (WEEKDAY(@checkweekday) < 6) THEN
        SET @workdays = @workdays+1;
      END IF;
      SET @daycount = @daycount+1;
      SELECT ADDDATE('@checkweekday', INTERVAL 1 DAY) INTO @checkweekday;
  END WHILE;
END;
SELECT @workdays;
```

Is someone able to assist?

**UPDATE**
I receive the same error with the following bit of code so it probably has something to do with this:

```
SET @workdays = 0;
IF (WEEKDAY('2013-06-13') < 6) THEN
  SET @workdays = @workdays+1;
END IF;
SELECT @workdays;
```

Comment: Do you have a function `FIRST_DAY()` ?

Comment: Yes I do.  The webhost actually has that function automatically.  I wrote my own and realized that when I use the function without mine it still works.  The first_day() is not where the error is anyway.  It passes it without a problem.

Comment: for those who end up here, I made a concise While-Loop example [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/7dcefc25d70a8f9147d10ce2ed881721)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have discovered that you cannot have conditionals outside of the stored procedure in mysql.  This is why the syntax error.  As soon as I put the code that I needed between

```
BEGIN
SELECT MONTH(CURDATE()) INTO @curmonth;
SELECT MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) INTO @curmonthname;
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE())) INTO @totaldays;
SELECT FIRST_DAY(CURDATE()) INTO @checkweekday;
SELECT DAY(@checkweekday) INTO @checkday;
SET @daycount = 0;
SET @workdays = 0;

  WHILE(@daycount < @totaldays) DO
    IF (WEEKDAY(@checkweekday) < 5) THEN
      SET @workdays = @workdays+1;
    END IF;
    SET @daycount = @daycount+1;
    SELECT ADDDATE(@checkweekday, INTERVAL 1 DAY) INTO @checkweekday;
  END WHILE;
END
```

**Just for others**:

If you are not sure how to create a routine in phpmyadmin you can put this in the SQL query

```
delimiter ;;
drop procedure if exists test2;;
create procedure test2()
begin
select ‘Hello World’;
end
;;
```

Run the query.  This will create a stored procedure or stored routine named test2.  Now go to the routines tab and edit the stored procedure to be what you want.  I also suggest reading http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/ if you are beginning with stored procedures.

The first_day function you need is:
[How to get first day of every corresponding month in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298288/how-to-get-first-day-of-every-corresponding-month-in-mysql)

**Showing the Procedure is working**
Simply add the following line below END WHILE and above END

```
SELECT @curmonth,@curmonthname,@totaldays,@daycount,@workdays,@checkweekday,@checkday;
```

Then use the following code in the SQL Query Window.

```
call test2 /* or whatever you changed the name of the stored procedure to */
```

**NOTE:** If you use this please keep in mind that this code does not take in to account nationally observed holidays (or any holidays for that matter).