# Altering column size of all the colums in a mysql table in a single command

Tags: mysql

In MYSQL, is there any option to set all column size to a fixed value? I have lot of columns in my table, so am searching for performing the changes in a single query without specifying each column. Please share that command if you know already.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing an information_schema select on your table and then do a while loop inside the query to update or alter the column values. Below is an example of how to select the information_schema of a table:

```
select * from information_schema.table_name
```

And here is a link to a stackoverflow question about MySQL While loops [WHILE LOOP with IF STATEMENT MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139074/while-loop-with-if-statement-mysql)

I hope that helps :-)