# SQL: DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type) skip weekends

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently using `DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)` to set a due date as a trigger in a mySQL Database.

What I'm wanting to know is if it is possible to skip weekends (Saturday, Sunday) as part of the trigger.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to modify `DATE_ADD(some Thursday, INTERVAL 3 DAY)` so that it'd be equal to next Tuesday?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create an own function for doing that. You can look how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17174413/2805519), for example (just use `function` instead of `procedure`). As for how to write such a function, [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30877.t-sql-extending-dateadd-function-to-skip-weekend-days.aspx)'s a working algorithm. The code is quite straightforward: it loops through days and skips weekends.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `DAYSADDNOWK`(addDate DATE, numDays INT) RETURNS date
BEGIN
    IF (WEEKDAY(addDate)=5) THEN
        SET addDate=DATE_ADD(addDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END IF;
    IF (WEEKDAY(addDate)=6) THEN
        SET addDate=DATE_ADD(addDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END IF;
    WHILE numDays>0 DO
       SET addDate=DATE_ADD(addDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
       IF (WEEKDAY(addDate)=5) THEN
           SET addDate=DATE_ADD(addDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
       END IF;
       IF (WEEKDAY(addDate)=6) THEN
           SET addDate=DATE_ADD(addDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
       END IF;
       SET numDays=numDays-1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN addDate;
END
```

Currently `SELECT DAYSADDNOWK(CURDATE(), 5)` yields `2016-03-07`, which is correct.

---

Of course you only can use it with days, so no arbitrary `interval`, but your question mentioned `date` datatype, and I don't quite see how one could add a month not counting working days.

Answer (score 0):

This function simply creates a list of dates starting at the date given in the arguments, and then figures out which date is x number of days (the interval) out while disregarding days 1 and 7 (which are Sunday and Saturday respectively on SQL Server).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_days_add_no_wknd] 
    (
    @start_date date
    , @interval int
    )
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN

declare @answer date

; with dates as 
    (
        select @start_date as date_val
        union all
        select dateadd(d, 1, date_val) as date_val
        from dates
        where date_val < dateadd(d, @interval * 10, @start_date)
    )
    , final as
    (
        select top 1 lead(ld.date_val, @interval, NULL) over (order by ld.date_val asc) as new_date_val
        from dates as ld
        where 1=1
        and datepart(dw, ld.date_val) not in (1,7) --eliminating weekends
    )
select @answer = (select new_date_val from final)

return @answer

END
```

It is worth nothing that this solution is dependent on having SQL Server 2012 or later, considering the use of the `lead()` function.

Comment: The question mentions mysql, in which this doesn't work.