# Select MySQL 3 months values

Tags: mysql

I need to Select three month's values from my database except the first day values of the third month.

For example:

I want to select values for three months since now: May, April, March without values from 1 March

Every day of month has 24 hour values for temperature and i want to exclude the first day of the third month like i said before.

Thank you!!

Comment: In each month you have one record in database (except March, where you have two records)? If not, which records you want to select? And I hope you store date in `date(time)` type column. You can add your attemps, what have you tried so far.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data, desired results, and a query you have tried.  A SQL Fiddle is also really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Get the first day of the month([in three months](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)) - [How to get first day of every corresponding month in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298288/how-to-get-first-day-of-every-corresponding-month-in-mysql)

```
CAST(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE)
```

get your query [between](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php) dates:

```
date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

and your query should be like:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND date != CAST(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 
   (date LIKE '____-05-__' 
 OR date LIKE '____-04-__' 
 OR date LIKE '____-03-__') 
AND date NOT LIKE '____-03-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) and [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function with [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) to filter your dates like:

```
YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND 
( MONTH(date) > MONTH(CURDATE()) - 2
  OR 
  ( MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) - 2
    AND
     DAY(date) > 1 ))
```