# How to form MySQL query to retrieve values dated to next month?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with a column dedicated solely to DATETIME values (e.g. "2010-11-12 12:34:56"). I'm trying to figure out how to select all rows from the table where the *month* is the month after the current month, *while also taking into account for year changes* (that is, if the current month is December in 2010, I want to select all values that are dated January 2011).

I have a hard time figuring out how to do it. This is my current query for selecting all values for the remainder of the current month:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uid = " . $_SESSION['uid'] . " AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time) AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NOW()) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time) AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW()) < EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_time) ORDER BY date_time";
```

I tried using the guide at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html (CURDATE and MOD), but I couldn't get it to work. :(

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009896/get-the-first-and-last-date-of-next-month-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... WHERE YEAR(date_time) = YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
AND MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

This one would be faster because it can utilize available indexes on the datetime field:

```
... WHERE date_time BETWEEN 
    DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),INTERVAL (DAY(NOW())-1) DAY)
    AND
    DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH),INTERVAL (DAY(NOW())) DAY)
```

Comment: Hm, in the end pretty similar to the answer to the linked question