# Get First & Last Day of Month from Year & Month variables

Tags: mysql, date, variables, time

Using MySql

I have the following variables (filled in with "3" and "2014" as an example):

```
SET @Month = 3;
SET @Year = 2014;
```

**Desired Results**

```
I'd like to get the first day of the month and the last day of the month separately, 
using the variables (avoiding any NOW() or CURDATE() formulas), in %Y-%m-%d format. In other words:

2014-03-01
2014-03-31
```

**I've tried many possibilities of the following base functions, plus some I've deleted**

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(`SELECT(@Year)-03-01`)
SELECT LAST_DAY('@Year-@Month')
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@Year,'-',@Month,'-01'),'%Y-%m-%d'), LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@Year,'-',@Month,'-01'),'%Y-%m-%d'));`

Comment: is that you are looking for [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/34043)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SET @Months = 3;
SET @Years = 2014;
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(concat(@Years, '-', @Months, '-01')), '%Y-%m-%d');
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE(concat(@Years, '-', @Months, '-01')));
```

'Year' and 'Month' are reserved function names in MySQL.  So I would suggest renaming it to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 
                INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))-1 DAY) AS firstOfNextMonth,
       LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), 
                INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS lastOfNextMonth
```

source: [Get the first and last date of next month in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009896/get-the-first-and-last-date-of-next-month-in-mysql)

Comment: This doesn't include the variables

Comment: i just post an example so you can adapt :P

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I need help with :) Integrating the variables

Comment: oh, ok. sorry i cant help :(