# Get the first and last working day date of some month in MySQL

Tags: mysql

It is very similar to 
[Get the first and last date of next month in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009896/get-the-first-and-last-date-of-next-month-in-mysql), but I want to Get the first and last working day date of some month in MySQL. Here, working day means simply Monday ~ Friday, or DAYOFWEEK(date) >= 2 and <= 6. Let's not think about holiday.

For example (I chose Feb as it should be most complicated due to leap)

```
2014-02 -> 2014-02-03 (Mon) ~ 2014-02-28 (Fri)
2015-02 -> 2015-02-02 (Mon) ~ 2015-02-27 (Fri)
2016-02 -> 2016-02-01 (Mon) ~ 2016-02-29 (Mon)
```

Comment: The most obvious question is: What constitutes a working day to you? They are not the same the world over

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT MIN(dt),MAX(dt) FROM calendar WHERE DAYOFWEEK (dt) NOT IN(1,7) AND dt BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31';
```

Comment: This is also a clever way - however make sure no day missing in table calendar

Comment: Yes. Calendar is a utility table with all dates. In practice, MySQL might not be the best tool for this. Rather solve this one in your application code, without the database at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code to start thinking about the problem. For the start (end) of month check for a weekday and advance (back up) one day if not. Repeat the test and possibly jump forward (backward) again. You'll never have to move more than twice.

```
/* <som> = start of month */
case
    when not (dayofweek(<som>) between 2 and 6)
    then
        case
            when not (dayofweek(<som> + 1) between 2 and 6)
            then <som> + 2
            else <som> + 1
        end
    else <som>
end

/* <eom> = end of month */
case
    when not (dayofweek(<eom>) between 2 and 6)
    then
        case
            when not (dayofweek(<eom> - 1) between 2 and 6)
            then <eom> - 2
            else <eom> - 1
        end
    else <eom>
end
```

I'm not a MySQL authority but you can use these substitutions I believe:

```
<som> -> date_sub(<dt>, interval dayofmonth(<dt>) - 1 day)
<eom> => last_day(<dt>)
```

There are different ways to rewrite this that are equivalent. The approach above was probably the way many would think about the problem initially but it's actually simpler than that. Since once I know which weekend day a date falls on I also know how many days until the next (previous) weekday. This can be handled as three easy cases:

```
case dayofweek(<som>)
    when 7 then <som> + 2
    when 1 then <som> + 1
    else <som>
end

case dayofweek(<eom>)
    when 7 then <eom> - 1
    when 1 then <eom> - 2
    else <eom>
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Feed day1 with first day of any month:

```
SELECT
if (
    (@w1 := dayofweek(@day1 := '2016-05-01')) = 1,
    adddate(@day1, interval 1 day), 
    if(@w1 = 7, adddate(@day1, interval 2 day), @day1)
) day_one,
if (
    (@w2 := dayofweek(@day2 := last_day(@day1))) = 1,
    adddate(@day2, interval -2 day), 
    if(@w2 = 7, adddate(@day2,interval -1 day), @day2)
) day_last
```

Brief explanation:

1. If first day is Sunday, add one day
2. If first day is Saturday, add two days

Give any day of a month, and get last day of the month,

1. If last day is Sunday, minus two days
2. If last day is Saturday, minus one day