# SQL variables month to covert date

Tags: mysql, sql

When adding variables to choose the month and year to query

- @Month = 5 @Year = 2017

I want to show two columns start_day and last_day of the @month and @year

```
startdaymonth       lastdaymonth
=============       ============
2017-05-01           2017-05-31
```

Comment: Mysqli and MS SQL Server? Very odd combination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the first and last date of next month in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009896/get-the-first-and-last-date-of-next-month-in-mysql)

Comment: Note that sql is for the storage and retrieval of data. It's not intended for random programming tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Month INT = 5 
DECLARE @Year INT = 2017



SELECT DATEADD(month,@Month-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)) as FirstDate,
       DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,@Month,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0))) AS LastDate
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate, *why* and *how* this solves the OPs issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Month int
DECLARE @Year int

set @Month = 5
set @Year = 2017

select DATEADD(month,@Month-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)) as startdaymonth // To get the first day of the month

select DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,@Month,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)))  as lastdaymonth  // To get the last day of the month
```

Comment: When you post any code as an answer, please also try to put some explanation of what that code does. It will help anyone understand your answer.

Comment: Sure, added here.

Answer (score 0):

**IF**, you are working with SQL Server use `eomonth()` function for last day of specified month

```
declare @Month int = 2,  @Year int = 2018

select cast(concat(@month,'/',1,'/',@year) as date), eomonth(concat(@month,'/',1,'/',@year))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte as (
select cast('2017-01-01' as date) as [FirstOfMonth]
union all
select dateadd(month, 1, FirstOfMonth) from cte
where datepart(year, FirstOfMonth) < 2018
)

select FirstOfMonth,
       dateadd(day, -1, LEAD(FirstOfMonth, 1) over (order by FirstOfMonth))
from cte
```

First part gets you first days of all months in 2017 plus first of Jan. of 2018. Second part gets the day before, i.e. last day of the month.

Try this and you'll get better understanding :) Only thing is, that you have to exclude last record, which is 2018-01-01 :)