# MYSQL - how to get the percentage of connected users grouped by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an efficient query to get the percentage of connected users grouped by month and user_group given the following 2 tables:

- connections(id, connection​_date, user_id)
- users(user_​id, user_group, creation_date)

I am using MySQL.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is the "percentage" a percentage of?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the percentage is the percewntage of users in a user_group who connected in a given month

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know how to express the percentage of users in a user_group who connected in a given month. Specifically I don't know how to get the percentage count.

Comment: Lastly, define "connected", because to achieve this you'll need to track (at least) a record per monthly connection. If you're only tracking the last active time, you'll get the results of people who connected that month (and never again after); if you're comparing to join date, it'll be incomparable to "connecting" in that month.

Comment: @Rogue each line in the table connections is a connection event. I do not really care about the creation_date but I mostly want to group the connection events by month and user_group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume connections.connection​_date & users.creation_date are of **datetime**.

To get the **percentage of connected users for a month** against the **total users as of to that month**, use:

```
SELECT u.user_group,  DATE_FORMAT(`c`.`connection​_date`, "%M %Y") AS month,
COUNT(DISTINCT u.`user_id`) / (SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM users WHERE users.creation_date <= adddate(last_day(`c`.`connection​_date`), 1) AND users.user_group = u.user_group) AS percentage,
COUNT(DISTINCT u.`user_id`) as loggedThisMonth,
(SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM users WHERE users.creation_date <= adddate(last_day(`c`.`connection​_date`), 1) AND users.user_group = u.user_group) AS totalRegisteredToMonth
FROM connections c LEFT JOIN users u ON c.`user_id` = u.`user_id`
GROUP BY u.user_group, DATE_FORMAT(`c`.`connection​_date`, "%M %Y")
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`c`.`connection​_date`, "%Y %m"), u.user_group ASC
```

This works by:

- counting the **DISTINCT users.user_​id** that have connected each month, thus preventing recounted users with multiple connections in a month `COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_​id)`
- using a **subselect** to calculate the **registered users** of a user group till that month `(SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM users WHERE users.creation_date <= adddate(last_day(`c`.`connection​_date`), 1) AND users.user_group = u.user_group)`

Reference:

```
adddate(last_day(`c`.`connection​_date`), 1)
```

return the [1st day of the next month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009896/get-the-first-and-last-date-of-next-month-in-mysql) date

Comment: Thanks @Jannes-Botis

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to join the 2 tables on the user id column.  Then simply group by user_group and month of connection date.  You can use DATEPART in SQL Server to do that.

Something like this:

```
SELECT u.user_group, DATEPART(MONTH, c.connection_date) AS month, COUNT(c.id)
FROM connections c INNER JOIN users u
  ON c.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_group, DATEPART(MONTH, c.connection_date);
```

Comment: hi @douglas.kirschman thanks for the answer. I am using MySQL and I don't think it supports the DATEPART. I will try using DATE_FORMAT.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: http://thisinterestsme.com/php-calculate-percentage-of-number/.

And here is the sql:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "UserName", "Password", "Database");
for($m=01;$m < 13; $m++) {

    $sql = "SELECT user_group FROM users WHERE creation_date LIKE '%" . $m . "%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $users = [];
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $users[] = $row["user_group"];
        };
    };
    $matchUserAmnt = count($users);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $user_amnt = $result->num_rows;
    //My number is the amount of users.
    $percent = round($matchUserAmnt / ($user_amnt / 100),2);
    echo "The percent of users who joined in the month " . $m . "is " . $percent;


};
```

Feel free to edit

Comment: Hi @code-lover Thanks for the answer, but I do not use php but python. I also believe that it is possible to achieve this result just using a SQL Request.

Comment: Cool, enjoy your python programming